# Ubuntu 20.04 won't boot after installing nvidia driver 450

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04, crash

I have built a desktop with a RTX 2060 Super and I would like to use my graphic card for machine learning. My Ubuntu 20.04 installation works fine but when I install **nvidia-driver-450** my computer doesn't boot anymore. I can access the BIOS but when the OS start, the computer crashes: everything stops (LEDs, Fans) except the power switch LED. I have to press the power button for several second to properly shut it down.

I have found that I can repair this if I access the recovery mode and uninstall Nvidia's driver. I have tried the installation through "*Additional Drivers*" of Ubuntu, the "*ubuntu-drivers*" command, the "*apt install*" command and from the official Nvidia website. All leads to the same result.

Is there a solution ? Has anyone else got the problem ?

Comment: can you fire up a tty (CTRL + ALT + F1 for example)? if yes, than you will have access to terminal, you can `sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-450` and eventually install noveau

Comment: I have not tried CTRL+ALT+F1 but I have purge nvidia-driver-450 in the root shell prompt of the recovery mode.

Comment: you will need to instal nouveau after purgin nvidia. seach on google: remove nvidia return to nouveau. There are good tutorials. The idea is that you need to have a graphics driver... otherwise the XSystem or Wayland will not fire up. Nouveau is the generic open source nvidia driver. With it you should have at least minimum functionalities and a starting point to fully troubleshoot the problem Btw. see that on ubuntu there is also a 455 nvidia driver available.

Comment: I have switch back to nouveau. My question is more: is there a way of installling the nvidia driver without crashing my computer ?

Comment: sometimes is a version specific problem which is solved in the next releases. What you can do is: 1) try another version of the drivers (as far as I know 455 is out, this is what I run on now). Eventually try also a older version (which should be stabler...) or 2) (generally if 1 fails) go deep into the logs and find the core problem

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and report if I found a solution